# How to parse Json object in ASP classic passed from jQuery

Tags: json, asp-classic, jquery

Using a jQuery dialog, on clicking OK I call `$.post( "save.asp", { id: 1, value: "abcxyz" } );` to pass the values to my ASP classic file that will update the database. I don't need a return value (unless it fails).

I'm a relative noob to jQuery, so I'm assuming I'm using JSON to pass the values to the ASP file. I just don't know what to do with them in ASP (using VBScript). I've seen things like [ASP Extreme](http://framework.lojcomm.com.br/app/docs/files/app/core/lib/json-class-asp.html), but I'm not clear on how to use them. I've tried referencing values via the Request collection, but no luck. All I want to do is take the values passed, parse them out, then save them to the database.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but this just isn't clicking for me.

Comment: You can, of course, use JScript in classic ASP. You need not resort to VBScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using associative arrays (*as they are called in <strike>javascript</strike> in PHP, Object Literal Notation in javascript*), but since you use them as the data to the `post` method they should get treated like normal form submits..

so in the asp side

```
pId = request.form("id")
pValue = request.form("value")
```

Comment: *as they are called in php*. It is called Object Literal Notation in JavaScript ;)

Comment: `.Form` is what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will default to sending the data as regular form parameters, not JSON.